# Getting the properties defined in an anonymous type sent via Func

Tags: c#, reflection, anonymous-types

Let's say we have the following classes defined like this

```
class Test {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Address {
    public string AddressText { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a need inside a method to do something with one or more of the properties in this class, and I would like to define which in a compile safe way. So I want to call the method like this:

```
MyFunction<Test>(t => new {t.Name, t.Address.AddressText});
```

Then inside MyFunction I need to know that "Name" and "Address.AddressText" are the selected properties, but I'm not sure how to get a hold of that

```
public void MyFunction<T>(Func<T, ?> param){
    ...
}
```

So my problem is I can't set the ? as the `TResult` of `Func` in any good way. If I could set that properly I guess I could take `typeOf(TResult).GetProperties()`, but I feel I'm missing a piece to get this to work.

**Update**

I see there is a confusion what I'm trying to do here. I'll give an example from the MongoDB driver that behaves the same way I would like mye code to do

So lets say that `testcoll` is a collection of `Test` objects. In that case this will work, and will only return me a list of an anonymous type that only has the Name property.

```
await testcoll.Find(t => t.Type == "sometype").Project(t => new {t.Name}).ToListAsync();
```

So the question is basically. Inside `Project`, how can I identify that `Name` is the properties I want to fetch from the DB, and return in the anonymous type in the result?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo. So used to writing prop to autocomplete the properties in the IDE ;)

Comment: Why can't you make a class/struct, or even a tuple? Can the caller select different properties?

Comment: Yes, it is in conjuction with a projection for a search. This is to indicate which fields I'm interested in getting back, and will be different every time I call MyFunction

Comment: Then `MyFunction` _can't_ know for sure that the properties `Name` and `AddressText` exist, right? You might not be "interested in those fields". `MyFunction` can't do this with compile time type safety, since there are no variadic generics, unless you are interested in a constant number of fields each time.

Comment: With compile type safety I meant calling the function. I want the parameter to be new {t.Name, t.Address.AddressText} and not a array of magic strings like this new []{ "Name", "Address.AddressText"}. But I understand that getting the actual values sent in will have to be done runtime, and that is perfectly fine.

Comment: I just want to be able to write the call to the function so I don't get any typos in the property names, and will get a compiler error if I change the definition of the class Test at some point to that those properties does not exist anymore

Comment: Have you considered using an interface?

Comment: I might be missing something (this is almost too simple), but how about replacing `?` with `List<object>`? Then you can create a list of the properties you want when you call the method. The only small problem I see is boxing...

Comment: Instead of anonymous type create a dedicated type and constructor with parameters.

Comment: If you want to be able to specify the members of your anonymous type dynamically, then there is no way to get a *static type safety* ensured by the compiler. This is just because of the *dynamic* nature of the use case. If you want a strong type safety, use a value tuple instead of an anonymous class (available with C# 7 and later).

Comment: I made an update with an example from the MongoDB driver that works the way I would like my code to work (except that I won't do anything towards a database but use it for something else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this now. It might be that my explanation in the questions is the problem. I want to get compile time safety for the parameter, and not getting the actual value compile time. That would of course not work.

So I want to be able to write

```
MyFunction<Test>(t => new {t.Name, t.Address.AddressText});
```

Instead of

```
MyFunction<Test>(new {"Name", "Address.AddressText"});
```

So that I wont get any typos in the parameters sent in, and will make sure that any change to the Test object will give me error here compile time.

I solved it like this:

```
public void MyFunction<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> lambda)
{
    List<string> arguments;
    if (lambda.Body is NewExpression)
    {
        var args = (lambda.Body as NewExpression).Arguments;
        arguments = args.Select(a =>
        {
                var aText = a.ToString();
                var dotIndex = aText.IndexOf(".");
                var result = aText.Substring(dotIndex + 1);
                return result;
            }).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
    <do whatever I need to do here with the arguments list>
}
```

So for the example above where the argument is `t => new {t.Name, t.Address.AddressText}` that will be converted to a list with the strings `"Name"` and `"Address.AddressText"` inside the method.